# WinRT app Screen resolution property

Tags: windows-runtime, screen-resolution, info

Is there a way to get the screen resolution in WinRt app?
I know in windows phone it's possible:

```
 var scaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
    var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;

        var x = (int) (bounds.Width*scaleFactor);
        var y = (int) (bounds.Height*scaleFactor);

      var resolution = String.Format("{0}x{1}", Math.Max(x, y),Math.Min(x,y));


But in winrt I don't have the RawPixelsPerViewPixel method...
```

Any ideas?

I've tried to follow the [Detect screen scaling factor in Windows 8.1 store apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157443/detect-screen-scaling-factor-in-windows-8-1-store-apps) post :

```
ResolutionScale resolutionScale = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().ResolutionScale;

    double scale = (double)resolutionScale / 100.0;

    var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;

    var x = (int)(bounds.Width * scale ) ;
    var y = (int)(bounds.Height * scale );


    var resolution = String.Format("{0}x{1}", Math.Max(x, y), Math.Min(x,y) );
```

But I am getting wrong numbers, for resolution 1920 x 1080 I get "1920x1008" and for resolution 800 x 600 I get "1126x743"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect screen scaling factor in Windows 8.1 store apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157443/detect-screen-scaling-factor-in-windows-8-1-store-apps)

Comment: Well, that post didn't really answers my question...I want to get the screen resolution - for instance : 720 x 1280

Comment: Well, once you have the scale factor, you can apply the same algorithm as the one you provided

Comment: I've tried, and I am getting something like : "1920x1008" when my screen resolution set to 1920 x 1080, when I am changing the resolution to something else, for example : 800 x 600 I am getting : "1126x743"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 var devices = PointerDevice.GetPointerDevices();
 var rect = devices.FirstOrDefault().ScreenRect;
 var dpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
 var width = rect.Width * dpi;
 var height = rect.Height * dpi;
```

This should work for both Desktop and Mobile in UWP apps.

Comment: The problem is that RawPixelsPerViewPixel is not defined in WinRT Api, only on windwos phone. That's why the code works on WP and not WinRT

Comment: Please tell me what platform you are exactly working on? The code is of no problem in UWP apps. When you mention WinRT, do you mean Windows RT 8.1?

Comment: Yes I mean Windows RT 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, based on a hack that I saw once for getting the Info about the Operating system in WinRT 8.1 app. I've created a temporary web view and navigated to string, in that html string I've called window.external.notify with javascript info about the resolution:

```
 var resolution = Math.max(window.screen.width, window.screen.height)  
                        + " x " + Math.min(window.screen.width, window.screen.height);
```

Then, in C# code I am receiving the parameter as webView event called.
I am not really satisfied with this solution, although it works fine...